# MPI processes got killed when the computer goes in sleeping mode

Tags: mpi, sleep-mode

I notice that all processes started under MPI are gone when the computer wakes up from a sleeping mode.
Is this normal behavior?  Is there any setting that keeps the processes alive?

Comment: You'll want to specify which MPI implementation you are using, what OS, what "sleep mode" you are referring to (S1/S2/S3/etc), and any other details you can share.

Comment: we are both using MPICH2 and Intel MPI.  OS is Windows 10 (not server).

Comment: Control Panel -> Power Options